# ¿Cómo puedo extraer información de un archivo de texto mediante split?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo donde tengo la siguiente información (siendo los números lo que ganaron en un día:

```
Juan:45:40:21:34

Pedro:34:45:43:30
```

Y quiero obtener los datos por separado en mi código de Python. Gracias por adelantado!

Lo que he intentado es:

```
with open("Salarios.txt", "r") as archivo:
    salarios = archivo.read()
    for cantidad in archivo.readlines():
        dinero_diario = cantidad.split(":")
        print(cantidad)
```

Pero aún soy muy novato y no sé cómo terminarlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo modifiqué. Es la primera vez que pregunto algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es simple. Si tienes una línea con

```
linea = "Juan:45:40:21:34"
```

basta con hacer un `split(':')` para obtener una lista con todos los valores.

Con la siguiente expresión

```
nombre, *valores = linea.split(":")
```

tomamos la lista de valores generados por `split` y asignamos el primer item de la lista (el nombre) a la variable `nombre`. Luego del nombre viene una cantidad variable de valores. Usando la sintaxis `*valores`, los recibimos todos en una lista, por si nos interesa usarlo a posteriori.

**Demo**

```
with open("salarios.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        nombre, *valores = linea.split(":")
        print(nombre)
```

salarios.txt

```
Juan:45:40:21:34
Pedro:34:45:43:30
```

produce:

```
Juan
Pedro
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo me quedó una duda para qué sirve la sintaxis de *valores?

Comment: A la izquierda de la asignación significa "esta es una lista, ponga aquí todos los valores restantes". Sin el "*", sería tratada como una variable escalar más.